# Как скопировать вложенный словарь?

Tags: python, словари

Я работаю с `multiprocessing` и использую `manager.dict()` для создания вложенного словаря, доступного разным процессам. Процессы вносят туда данные и все работает отлично, но я хочу использовать `pickle`\`dill` для выгрузки словарь, чтобы запуская программу заново мне не нужно было еще раз заполнять вложенный словарь. Но так как словарь имеет тип `multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy` загрузить его, после сохранения на компьютере нельзя. И я подумал перед тем как выгружать, поменять тип с `multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy` на `dict`, но метода который так делает, я не нашел. Есть ли алгоритм который бы прошелся по всему вложенному словарю и вернул копию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как обычно в таких случаях, если у класса нет специального метода для преобразования в словарь, можно просто сделать новый словарь, подав ему на вход ваш класс:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
man_dct = manager.dict({'test': 123, 'fafdf': {2323: 234234, 'sdfsdf': 'sdfsdf'}})
print(type(man_dct), man_dct)
dct = dict(man_dct)
print(type(dct), dct)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy'> {'test': 123, 'fafdf': {2323: 234234, 'sdfsdf': 'sdfsdf'}}
<class 'dict'> {'test': 123, 'fafdf': {2323: 234234, 'sdfsdf': 'sdfsdf'}}
```

Если такие словари рекурсивно вложены, можно их рекурсивно обойти и превратить в обычные словари:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager
from multiprocessing.managers import DictProxy

def to_dict(item):
    if isinstance(item, DictProxy):
        return {k: to_dict(v) for k, v in item.items()}
    return item

manager = Manager()
man_dct = manager.dict({'test': 123, 'fafdf': manager.dict({2323: 234234, 'sdfsdf': 'sdfsdf'})})
print(type(man_dct), man_dct)
dct = to_dict(man_dct)
print(type(dct), dct)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy'> {'test': 123, 'fafdf': <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x1bfa660ccd0>}
<class 'dict'> {'test': 123, 'fafdf': {2323: 234234, 'sdfsdf': 'sdfsdf'}}
```

Comment: Увы если бы все было так просто) мой словарь вложенный, вложенные словари также имеют тип multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy, просто обернуть в dict не получится, вложенные словари тип не поменяют

Comment: @ДаниилСинякин Ладно, я добавил вариант с рекурсивным обходом